# ASP.NET File Upload - > Translation from PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, file-upload

I posted something similar but I am changing my question around enough to warrant a new post.

I am trying to handle a posted file to an aspx page (C#).  I am told this is not possible without a postback from `<input type=file>` or the asp file uploader. However, I have a PHP script does this perfectly, so I am really hoping it can be accomplished in C#/ASP.NET.

I am trying to post an image form a mobile device, so an actual `<input type=file>` is not an option.

Any thoughts and advise would really help!

PHP:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://urlgoeshere.om/uploads/{$file}";
}
else {
    echo "No files uploaded\n";
}

?>
```

How can this be done in ASP.NET?

Comment: what if someone uploads a `backdoor.php` or `backdoor.asp`.

Comment: How does stuff get uploaded to the php handler? That must be from an '<input type=file>' surely.

Comment: I removed the filters from the script to make it shorter.  But I am only allowing image files through.  Good point though.

Comment: @Martin: from an iPhone app as an HTTP POST request.

Comment: @Brett - So the app submits a post in the same format as a browser file upload would be and you want to be able to handle the request without a corresponding .aspx page?

Comment: @martin: I want to be able to handle the uploaded file (save it to disk) in the Page_Load event of an aspx file (call it upload.aspx).  You think this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on code [from here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HttpHandlerFileUploader.aspx)

This seems to do the job at accepting a random file upload.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = "uploads/";

        if (Request.Files.Count <= 0)
        {
            Response.Write("No file uploaded");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; ++i)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[i];
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath + file.FileName));
                Response.Write("File uploaded");
            }
        }

    }
```